# angular2-materialize chips implementation

Tags: jquery, angular, materialize

I'm trying to implement the examples of materialize-css chips found [here](http://materializecss.com/chips.html), under the "Javascript Plugin Usage" heading, in Angular with angular2-materialze. I have followed the instructions for angular-cli installation found in the [docs](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize). I'm especially interested in the following implementation:

HTML

```
<div class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
$('.chips').material_chip();
$('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
    placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
  });
```

How do I convert that to Angular code? What does my template and component need to have for this to work?

I have tried changing the HTML to this, but it didn't work:

```
<div materialize class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example code here: https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/blob/master/sample/src/app/components/chips.ts
This is the demo: http://angular2-materialize.surge.sh/#/Chips

In your code, you should use material_chip instead of chip:

```
<div class="chips" materialize="material_chip" [materializeParams]="[chipsPlaceholder]"></div>
```

Answer taken from: https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/293